# jquery incompatibility in browsers in fetching 'selected' text

Tags: jquery, browser, selected

I wrote my code in I.E 8:

```
$(".percent_hours option:selected").each(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("text");
```

firefox and chrome doesn't get the selected value (empty string).

I changed the code to:

```
$(".percent_hours option:selected").each(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr("value");
```

but now I.E. doesn't get the selected value.

Is there any way to handle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get the text , use `.text()`, get the value use `.val()`